# Using Keras VGG19 preprocess_input function during model training

Tags: python, keras, vgg-net

I am using VGG19 model pretrained on ImageNet dataset with top-layers (from flatten till the last output layer) removed.

The problem I am solving takes in multiple inputs that are from [ModelNet dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/balraj98/modelnet40-princeton-3d-object-dataset)  (a modified version actually). So what I am doing is, I am using VGG19 to extract features from these images for me and then I concatenate the output which is further fed to the rest of the network i.e. the top of the model that I have created according to my need and the number of classes (20 in my case). This is my code for the model I am using (if needed for reference):

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

input_1 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image1')              
input_2 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image2')              
input_3 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image3')              
input_4 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='image4')              

base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

x1 = base_model(input_1, training=False)
x2 = base_model(input_2, training=False)
x3 = base_model(input_3, training=False)
x4 = base_model(input_4, training=False)

x = concatenate([x1, x2, x3, x4])

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x) 
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(20, activation='softmax', name='class_out')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4], outputs)
print(model.summary())
```

Now, I want to know that **is it necessary to use 'from keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input' for my input images before training the model? or should I use this function while predicting only?**
As for my input, they are already normalized values that I am using for model training via a custom made data-loader function; which simply returns the generator of 4 normalized input images and a class_output, like this:

```
# The output from data-loader function
# where x_batch are values normalized by x_batch[i,j]/255
 yield {'image1': x_batch[:, 0], 
          'image2': x_batch[:, 1], 
          'image3': x_batch[:, 2], 
          'image4': x_batch[:, 3], }, {'class_out': y_batch}
```

However, **whenever I use preprocess_input instead of plain normalization**, my output image is a weird looking image like this:
[image: processed image with keras preprocess_input]

I do not understand this scenario.. if anyone can help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

VGG19 requires your input image to be a BGR image, not RGB image. And so, `keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input` will convert the input images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling. For more information about your model click [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/vgg/#vgg19-function), and more about the preprocessing function can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg19/preprocess_input)

So, if you are already converting your images from RGB to BGR before passing to the model, then you don't need to use `keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input` on your input images.

Comment: I read keras VGG19 documentation on preprocessing the input and I understand that it needs to convert images to BGR.. but I am still confused if I should normalize my values by dividing those with 255 (as mentioned in my code) OR should I use preprocess_input function for this! OR should I normalize using /255 and then I use preprocess_input as well?

Comment: @stackersTech101 I'm not sure about the range, but I remember once performing transfer learning with vgg16 with the image pixel values ranging from 0 to 1 and achieved acceptable results. So I suggest you can try different ranges (`[0,1]`, `[0,255]`, `[-1,1`]) and see which one performs the best. It would be helpful to others if you post your results here afterwards.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering:
the preprocess_input function turns rgb to bgr as mentioned and also zero centers each color channel, which means the input is expected in a range from [-127, 127]. However, you should use the preprocess_input function instead of doing it yourself as the centering is done with repsect to ImageNet